# Unexpected token, expected; When calling a function in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to call a function when a button is pressed. 
After I add the function, it errors out with the Unexpected token error.

I followed instructions from all previous similar questions but it doesn't solve my case. Please help.

```
_handlePress: function() {
  console.log("Butto GO!")
}

export default class fun extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
       <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._handlePress()}>
            <Image style={{width: 50, height: 50}} source={require('./go.png')} />
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
  );
 }
}
```

Also, Should the called function be defined before the default class?

Comment: `this._handlePress` means _handlePress is a member of the same class as the function it's called from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the function behind render, after the class and I don't know if u do `test : function()` it works there so try my example and give feedback

```
export default class fun extends Component {

  _handlePress() {
    console.log("Butto GO!")
  }

  render() {
    return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
         <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._handlePress()}>
            <Image style={{width: 50, height: 50}} source={require('./go.png')} />
         </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
   }
  }
```

or if you want to do behind the export class you can use `_handlePress()` instead of `this._handlePress()` and it should work!

Example:

```
'use strict';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View,Text,TouchableOpacity,Alert,Dimensions} from 'react-native';

const windows = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class Feed extends Component {

  _test(){
    Alert.alert("Test");
    console.log("It worked!");
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._test()}>
             <Image source={require('../image/2.jpg')} style={{height: windows.height, width: windows.width, }} />
          </TouchableOpacity> 
       </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I still get the error. Unexpected token - on line console.log('Button Go!')

Comment: try `console.log("Button");`

Comment: Weird , show me the full stuff , imports and all its a simple onpress it should work, and did you do the exact what i did? deleting the `: function()` and calling it inside?

Comment: Awesome. It works now. I was expecting the auto-reload on the simulator to fix it. Re-running made it work Thanks!. Also, where do I see the logs I am trying to print ?

Comment: No problem ! If you install some package or something always reload all the thing if you change only code just Reload the app and should work .